# How can there be any indicative if-clauses?

Tags: history, expression-choice, subjunctive-mood

As far as I know, if-clauses always describe theoretical situations. Sometimes the theory is very obvious and self-evident, but it remains a theory. So how can we use the indicative in if-clauses all the time? Is that not the mode of facts and statements? We do have a mode for theories; why don't we use it? Why doesn't every sentence with an if have to contain at least one verb in the subjunctive?

Comment: The subjunctive is used in false-to-fact "if" clauses.  But not all "if" clauses are false-to-fact, so not all of them use the subjunctive.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the answer.